# Proving a set is a subgroup of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, and let $K=\{x\in G : xax^{-1}\in H \;\;\mathrm{iff} \;\;a\in H\}$.
Prove $H$ is a subgroup of $K$. (In a previous exercise, we prove $K$ is a subgroup of $G$)

The way the definition of each set is interwoven is throwing me off my feet for proving this.

Comment: you only have to show that $H \subseteq K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h\in H$.

Check now for membership of $h$ in $K$:

Let $a\in H$. Then $hah^{-1}\in H$ since $h$, $a$, and $h^{-1}$ are in $H$ and $H$ is a subgroup of G. Thus $h\in K$ by the definition of $K$.

[Strictly speaking, this only proves one side of the iff statement. I'll leave the other side to you]

Comment: Would the other side go like this?: Let $h, hah^{-1}\in H$. Since $H$ is closed under operation and inverses, then $h^{-1}\in H$, so $a\in H$, and $h\in K$.

Comment: yeah, pretty much

Answer (score 1):

If $h\in H$, $h\in K$ means
$$hah^{-1}\in H\iff a\in H.$$
Indeed $\;hah^{-1}\in H\iff a\in h^{-1}Hh$. This results from the fact that, by definition of a subgroup, $\; h^{-1}Hh=H$.